# fixed header overlaps text input on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Given a website with a fixed header and fixed footer... if you try to input text with my Galaxy Samsung S3 the browser (Chrome) zoomes the input form an opens an onscreen-keyboard.

But the fixed header and footer is still there in the screen.. so there is almost no space anymore and the input form is overlapped by the fixed css elements.

Isn't the mobile browser supposed to "hide" all the other elements, also fixed elements, when it goes into text input mode?